# Javascript is not creating new instance of function in Node.JS API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, callback

I am developing a Node.JS application in which I have an endpoint as shown below:

```
const streamService = require('./stream.service');
module.exports = function (app) {

    /**
     * Below API will send all streams data according to the parameters passed in query parameters.
     */
    app.get("/streams", async function (request, response) {

        var device_id = (!req.query.device_id) ? "" : req.query.device_id;
        var userid = (!req.query.user) ? "" : req.query.user;

        var streams = streamService.getAllStreams(device_id,userid);

        response.send(streams);
    });
}
```

This calls getAllStreams function which is written in some other file. While the function getAllStreams is getting executed if any other API hit comes then it is overriding the data which I am getting from query parameters and affecting the response of 'getAllStreams' function. I have also observed that the response is a mixture of both the API calls expected result. I am willing to know if I am doing anything wrong while calling function. Basically it should create a new instance of that function for every call but it is not creating.

I know this is a very strange behavior of JavaScript I have noticed today. I have never ever expected that but I am looking for any solution. Please note that I have checked the above said scenario multiple times by putting some logs at both server and client side.

Thank you in advance for your help. :-)

Comment: Are there any variables in the function `getAllStreams` wherein the values get changed because of some other process or function call?

Comment: I don't think it's JS's fault here... maybe the library that you have keeps state and every call to that library modifies the state? that sounds more reasonable than JS doing some weird thing with functions...

Comment: Every execution of a function does create a new closure; those per-execution closures do not share local-varaible state. The problem here appears ot be that one call to `streamService.getAllStreams` affects a later call to `streamService.getAllStreams`, I think? (I don't practically understand what the service does.) It sounds like `streamService.getAllStreams` needs to be written (or used) in a way such that it doesn't cause this undesired behavior.

Comment: If possible, I think you need to share the code for `streamService.getAllStreams`.

Comment: @abondoa, That code is really huge. I can't share that here. I am sorry for that.

Comment: @LearningEveryday, There is no any variable like that. I have checked the same.